# Is it possible to call cuSPARSE routines from kernel functions?

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to call `cuSPARSE` routines from the GPU, that is, from inside a kernel using dynamic parallelism?

`libcublas_device.a` enables to call `cuBLAS` routine from the GPU. I supposed `libcusparse_device.a` would exist and allow to call `cuSPARSE` routines from the GPU. However, it seems that file does not exist. Is this possible? If yes, how? If not, does NVIDIA plan to deliver such features in next GPU generations ?

FGH

Note : I run Unix (CentOs) + I use a "Tesla K20m" GPU (CUDA 5.5, Compute capability 3.5)

Comment: The documentation says: _It is implemented on top of the NVIDIA® CUDA™ runtime
(which is part of the CUDA Toolkit) and is designed to be called from C and C++._

Comment: The answer is no.  @JackOLantern do you want to provide an answer?  I would upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the cuSPARSE Library documentation for CUDA 6.5 (Release Candidate version):

> The `cuSPARSE` library contains a set of basic linear algebra subroutines used for
>   handling sparse matrices. It is implemented on top of the NVIDIA® CUDA™ runtime
>   (which is part of the CUDA Toolkit) and is designed to be called from C and C++.

Accordingly, as of **August 2014**, you can't call `cuSPARSE` routines from kernel functions. The answer to your question is then: **NO**.